# ASP.Net Web API model constructor binding - Wrong constructor being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple ASP.Net Web API controller in an otherwise unchanged MVC4 Web API project that has a POST method that takes a Values class.  When I do a:

**POST /api/values** with a body of **{ name: "somename" }**

the Values() constructor gets called instead of the Values(string name) one. Normally, this isn't a problem because the Name property would have a public set and Web API would call it after construction. In this case it is private, so I get a default instance of Values.

If I remove the Values(int) ctor then it does call the Values(string) ctor.

Is there a reason ModelBinding isn't choosing the ctor with the name parameter?

Here's the example code:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPIPlayground.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public void Post(Values value)
        {
            var a = value.ID; // == 0
            var b = value.Name; // == null
        }
    }

    public class Values
    {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        private Values() { }
        public Values(int id) { ID = id; }
        public Values(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
}
```

I have already looked at: [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) and [WebAPI Parameter binding under the hood](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx) among many other sites, but I do not understand this behavior.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but the constructor you claim it should be calling does not have the same method signature as your POST body (you haven't provided an `int` parameter).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for catching that. It shouldn't have been there. That was one of the last things I tried before posting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're talking about deserialization here, not model binding. Try adding this attribute to the constructor you want to have used:

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Values(string name)
```

That should do it for the Json.NET case, but it won't work in XML. Maybe that's all you care about.

Comment: Good point. I'll try this out (or something like it), and post back details.

Comment: Don't forget using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: This did work. We are only doing json right now. Now that I know it's a deserialization problem I'm sure I could get this to work for xml as well if needed. Thanks!

Comment: I am not posting JSON, so this is not working.
Is there a different way to do it, or do I need to change how I am posting things?